# Como Conectar ao Banco lendo arquivo INI (Função e Classe)

Tags: php, ini

Como posso conectar ao banco de dados (PHP em 3 Camadas [Fachada / Repositório / Banco]) lendo as informações de um arquivo .ini e atribuindo esses valores em uma função dentro de uma classe ?

Banco.php

```
class Banco {
  var $server;
  var $bd;
  var $user;
  var $password;
  var $erro;
  var $result;
  var $conexao;

  function Banco ($user="usuario",$pass="senha",$db="banco",$srv="servidor") {
    if(!$this -> SetConexao($srv,$user,$pass)) {
      $this -> SetErro("Erro de Conexão - ".mssql_get_last_message($this -> GetConexao()));
      mssql_close();
      return false;
    }
    if(!$this -> SetBd($db)) {
      $this -> SetErro("Banco não Encontrado - ".mssql_get_last_message($this -> GetConexao()));
      mssql_close();
      return false;
    }
  }
.......... mais código .........
}
```

Arquivo .INI

```
[BANCO]
user = usuario
pass = senha
db = banco
srv = servidor
```

Lendo Arquivo .INI

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
$cUser = $ini['BANCO']['user'];
$cPass = $ini['BANCO']['pass'];
$cDb = $ini['BANCO']['db'];
$cSrv = $ini['BANCO']['srv'];

Class .... {

blabla.....

function Banco ($user=$cUser,$pass=$cPass,$db=$cDb,$srv=$cSrv) { <-- Erro ao conectar ao banco
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer esse tipo de conexão sem ter que desfazer as camadas de conexão em php ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está misturando a definição da classe com a instanciação do objeto. Não se passa o `=` assim diretamente. Você precisa fazer algo dessa forma:

```
<?php

// Aqui vem a definação da classe
class Banco { 
// ...
}

// Aqui a instanciação
$ini = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
$cUser = $ini['BANCO']['user'];
$cPass = $ini['BANCO']['pass'];
$cDb = $ini['BANCO']['db'];
$cSrv = $ini['BANCO']['srv'];


$db = new Banco();
$db->Banco($cUser, $cPass, $cDb, $cSrv);
```

Comment: Eu tinha feita dessa forma, porém estava realizando a leitura do ini fora da função da instancia do banco, foi falta de atenção mesmo. Obrigado